# i wan to do this in react native please giveme solutions i am new in this

Tags: react-native, long-press, touchableopacity

https://medium.com/@pavolfulop/repeat-onpress-action-when-holding-button-react-native-2c697cf28032

Hi i need help to do this in react native giveme a solution

Comment: The medium article you posted *is* in React Native. In order for us to give you better answers, can you explain what about that article doesn't work for your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I asked for clarification in the comments, but if other folks find this looking for similar issues, you might consider using the [onLongPress](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable#onlongpress) prop, instead of creating one yourself with `onPressIn` and `onPressOut`.